# Forms authentication infinite loop

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms-authentication, asp.net-4.0

I have an application that works great on localhost with forms authentication.

I deployed it to the deployment machine and it to the build machine and received and endless set of 302 redirects.

I try logging onto the deployment machine and access the page via the deployment machines ip and it works again.

So it is not working when I try and access the site from my computer to the build computer.

What could be causing this?

Comment: did you check that the login and default page properties are set correctly on the deployment machine?

Comment: They are the same as the development machine

Comment: Can you clarify: viewing the site on the local machine, addressed by IP works fine. From any other workstation, addressing the machine (by hostname or DNS alias) you get the 302 loop?

Comment: yeah... so I am on the local machine, but I use the ip address and it works ok.  Then I do the same thing from the dev machine going to the deployment machine I end up trapped in a 302

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem a few weeks ago. My problem was that my `Default.aspx` required roles/permissions that the user I was trying to log with did not have.

```
Default.aspx (anonymous user) -> Login.aspx -> [logged in] -> Default.aspx (user denied access) -> automatic redirect to the main page -> Default.aspx (user denied) -> endless loop.
```

I fixed it by removing any permissions required for my default page and making sure the permissions in my web.config were Ok.

Comment: I'm not sure what this means..  I am redirecting to a page (that is not default) and it needs to be protected for deny anonymous....

Comment: @zachary what i mean is that make sure your default page (whatever that is) does not require a security role the logged user is not in.

Answer (score 0):

There's most likely an IIS configuration issue.

- Determine that your Authentication is set to allow anonymous.
- Ensure your default page is specified in the list in IIS.

Comment: I don't think I specity a default page.... authentication is set to allow anonymous....

Answer (score 0):

And it was because the time on the server was different then the time on my client machine.  Who knew such a thing could happen?  Not me.

The sad part is I changed the time hours ago but I put it at AM instead of PM.  Awesome!

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue on a Windows XP machine with IIS 5.1 for a .NET 1.1 site by changing the ASP.NET version correctly to 1.1.4322 instead of 2.0.50727 (what it was set to).

Just wanted to mention that in case it helps someone else. I feel silly for not realising that sooner. :-)